# How to find the structure of repeating elements in XML/HTML

Tags: string, algorithm, text

I'm currently trying to solve a programming problem. I'm trying to find repeated structures in any HTML page, and I'm trying to retrieve the values of those elements.

For example, I've got a HTML page with repeating elements, like the following:

```
<html>
<body>
  <ul>
     <li>green</li>
     <li>orange</li>
     <li>red</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

In this code, I'd like to detect that there's a repeating block (the 'li' items), and I'd like to extract their values. Another HTML example:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>John</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Simon</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

In this example I'd like to detect that the structure  is repeated, and get the values [1,John] and [2,Simon] from that.

My question is: is there a simple algorithm to do something like this, or, if not, how would you approach something like this?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: You will have to give more details. In the second example <td> is also repeated so extracting 1 and `John` also seems a valid solution for me. Also should the repeating elements follow without interuption(e.g. if there was some text between the two rows of the table would we still be interested in them. Overall you have to define `repeating block` and `their values`.

Comment: When you define `repeating block`, also indicate whether otherwise-matching blocks at different levels of nesting count as matches, whether repeating blocks can overlap, etc.

Comment: @Holf I'm using Java, but I'm more interested in the approach than in the actual code.

Comment: @izomorphius Good catch! I think I'm then looking for the largest (in characters) block of repeated structure in this particular example. So <td></td> is a repeating block, but <tr><td></td><td></td></tr> is a bigger repeated block.

Answer (score 2):

A rather rudimentary python program that detects the duplicated tr-td-td tag sequence and duplicated td tags is shown below.  With your second html example saved in file `xml.html`, the program prints out:

```
tr.td.td 

td 1
td John
tr.td.td 

td 2
td Simon
Counter({'td': 4, 'tr.td.td': 2, 'table.tr.tr': 1})
```

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
from collections import Counter

def sot(r, depth):
    tags = r.tag
    for e in r.getchildren():
        tags += '.' + sot(e, depth+1)
    r.tail = tags
    cc[r.tail] += 1
    return r.tag

def tot(r, depth):
    if cc[r.tail] > 1:
        print r.tail, r.text
    for e in r.getchildren():
        tot(e, depth+1)

cc = Counter()
p=ET.parse ("xml.html")
sot(p.getroot(), 0)
tot(p.getroot(), 0)
print cc
```